# How to convert List<T> to an Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity I've decided to make a custom editor for my component.
The component itself has a list of objects that I've declared as List.

The Editor targets this like this:

```
myCustomList = serializedObject.FindProperty ("myCustomList");
```

The problem is that when I try to get/set value of the `myCustomList` using `myCustomList .objectReferenceValue = modifiedCustomList as List< MyCustomObject >` tells me that List< MyCustomObject> cannot be cast as Object.

I tried to simply set the values through myCustomList = (target as TargetClass).myCustomList, but (of course) when I pressed the play button the objects instances were reset to a fresh new list.

How do I cast List to an Object? Or how to use the serializedObject to get/set data of types like Lists?

Comment: So to clarify your question, are you asking why you can't cast your `modifiedCustomList` as a `List<MyCustomObject>`, meaning you are starting with a list of just objects, and wanting to convert them to your custom object but can't seem to cast them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youll need to iterate through the object like so...

```
 SerializedProperty myCustomList = serializedObject.FindProperty ("myCustomList");

    for (int i = 0; i < myCustomList .arraySize; i++)
    {
        SerializedProperty elementProperty = myCustomList.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);

        //Since this the object is not UnityEngine.Object you can not convert them the unity way.  The compiler can determine the type that way so.....

       MyCustomList convertedMCL = elementProperty.objectReferenceValue as System.Object as MyCustomList;
    }
```

Since SerializedProperty is not a UnityEngine.Object you can not convert them the unity way.  The compiler can not determine the type that way.

A discussion on the subject can be found [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/200123/editor-how-to-do-propertyfield-for-list-elements.html).

Comment: I'll give this a go, looks very promising!

Comment: Worked for me. Hope all goes well.

Comment: can't really transform elementProperty's objectReferenceValue to MyCustomObject... Trying to look for a way to do this now

Comment: I edited the answer to include a way for you to cast to your custom object.

Comment: BTW Things like this really erk me.  Unity should provide more documentation on things like this.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm trying to make it work, making a MyCustomObject [Serializable], but still after using your method the object becomes null :(

Comment: Perhaps you could show what your custom type looks like as well as the code where you are trying to cast it?

Comment: The problem was that my value object class and the class that had an extended editor had those fields accessible as `internal` and thats why it was always returning `null`